# Local variable might not be initialized before accessing - after calling .TryParse()

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have this piece of code:

```
var kv = new Dictionary<int, string>() { ... };

var kv30Valid = kv.ContainsKey(30) && int.TryParse(kv[30], out var kv30Value);

myObject.nullableInt = kv30Valid ? (int?)kv30Value : null;
```

Note: myObject is a POCO class representing a table row, that's why nullable int.

I cannot compile my code because I get compiler error on the last line:

> Local variable 'kv30Value' might not be initialized before accessing

In which case can it be unintialized and how to properly handle the case to allow valid code?

I need to populate the myObject properties with values from the kv (if they are present) parsed to their respective values.

**Solution:**
Moving the condition into TryParse() method solved the problem.

```
var kv30Valid = int.TryParse(kv.ContainsKey(30) ? kv[30] : null, out var kv30Value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definite assignment analyzer has limitations (as it must, yada yada yada halting problem, etc). Although we can look at this code and conclude that it'll only access `kv30value` if `ContainsKey` returned true and thus `TryParse` was called, it's too "separate" for the analyzer to be able to see this.

If this was inside an `if` block using `kv30valid` it might be able to see it but even then I'm not sure.

Comment: Not my most elegant solution but I solved it by:
`var kv30Valid = int.TryParse(kv.ContainsKey(30) ? kv[30] : null, out var kv30Value);`

Answer (score 0):

> In which case can it be unintialized

When `kv.ContainsKey(30)` returns `false`, `int.TryParse()` isn't called, and `kv30Value` won't be assigned.

To simplify the issue, you have an unassigned variable:

```
bool test; // declared, but not assigned
if (test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test is true");
}
```

This won't compile, because `test` is not assigned.

Now a method with an `out` parameter will definitely assign the variable:

```
bool test;
Assign(out test);

if (test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test is true");
}

private static void Assign(out bool foo)
{
    foo = true;
}
```

This will print "Test is true".

Now if you make the assignment conditional:

```
bool test;

bool condition = DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now;
if (condition)
{
    Assign(out test);
}

if (test) { ... }
```

You'll be back at the compiler error:

> CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `test`

Because the assignment of `test` can't be guaranteed by the compiler, so it forbids further use of that variable.

Even if the usage of the variable uses the same condition:

```
bool test;

bool condition = DateTime.Now > DateTime.Now;
if (condition)
{
    Assign(out test);
}

if (condition && test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test is true");
}
```

Then still the compiler refuses you to use `test`.

That's exactly the same as with your `&& int.TryParse(..., out)` code. The right side of the `&&` is conditionally executed, thus the compiler will refuse to let you use the variable that's potentially unassigned.

Regarding the discussion below and the downvote on my answer, if you want to know the **why** behind all this, see the C# language specification chapter 5.3 Definite assignment. Basically put, you get this error because the compiler does a best effort attempt at statically analyzing whether the variable is assigned.

> how to properly handle the case to allow valid code?

Declare it above, and assign it a sensible default value:

```
int kv30Value = 0;
var kv30Valid = kv.ContainsKey(30) && int.TryParse(kv[30], out kv30Value);
```

Or simplify the code by moving it into an `if`, where it'll be definitely assigned:

```
if (kv.ContainsKey(30) && int.TryParse(kv[30], out var kv30Value))
{
    myObject.nullableInt = kv30Value;
}
```

Comment: When `kv.ContainsKey(30)` returns `false` then variable `kv30Valid` = false and `int.TryParse()` is not called.

Then second condition should assign null to `myObject.nullableInt` but not report compiler error.

There is no int.TryParse(value, out int); This is .net core 2.0 C#7.0

Comment: _"and int.TryParse() is not called"_ - and that's exactly the problem, because **the `out` part of `TryParse(in, out)` will assign the variable**. The compiler tells you that that assignment is possibly not reached (because it's called as the right part of `left && right`, where `left` can be `false` thus `right` won't be called), which can cause trouble if code further on tries to use that unassigned variable.

Comment: that's not the problem because the right side of the tertiary operator is never reached.

Comment: That **is** the problem, because when the right side isn't reached, the variable isn't assigned... And therefore the compiler won't allow you to use a probably unassigned variable.

Comment: Do you ignore the fact I am talking about the last line of code? You know what ?:; does?

Comment: No, I don't ignore that, you didn't make that clear. And you mean the conditional operator. That's moot. The compiler doesn't execute your code, it analyzes it. It's not "that smart" (see Damien's answer, keyword being "halting problem"). It sees a conditional assignment; it refuses any further usage of that variable, regardless of whether that usage itself is conditional or not, see last edit.

Comment: Your answer is not valid because there is no such method signature for TryParse(). Only "out var" is allowed.
Are you saying that the static code analyzer is smart enough to evaluate my code and conclude that I will potentially use an uninitialized variable but not smart enough to evaluate the same code using this variable will never execute? Sounds more like a bug to me.

Comment: My answer _is_ valid. What signature are you talking about? You're calling the method `int.TryParse(string s, out int result)` and you're doing so using the C# 7.0 feature called "inline out variables": `int.TryParse(kv[30], out var kv30Value)`. That the compiler doesn't implement a feature you'd expect it to is not a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186410/discussion-between-slavomir-danas-and-codecaster).

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw with your example `if (condition && test) { Console.WriteLine("Test is true"); }`.
If you have a look at the IL assembly then you're comparing DateTime.Now to DateTime.Now which refer to one memory address. This comparison always evaluates to false, thus the `if (condition) { Assign(out test); }` code block is not even compiled into the final assembly which in turn makes test variable always unassigned.

Comment: Optimizations come after language rules. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. I'm stating what rules the compiler complies to, and why that rule causes the compiler error you're getting. Are you saying I'm wrong, or don't you understand my answer, or are you simply trying to argue? `DateTime.Now` doesn't refer to a "memory address", it's a property getter that returns a new `DateTime` on each call, and definitely isn't optimized away in a release build.

Comment: https://imgur.com/kq18XQ1 Let's replace the code with proposed false then. https://imgur.com/XC3SsTy

Comment: That's ReSharper. They don't write the C# language spec.